# Stack Callback implementation C++

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, callback, stack

I have to make a stack that can store function calls to other functions basically acting as an"undo" stack.

I am really struggling with the actual implementation of the callback in the stack.

Here is what I have so far

Struct/Stack Implementation

```
struct Node {
    void (*fn)(void*);
    struct Node *next;
    }; 

    struct Node* Top = nullptr;
```

IMplentation of Push and Pop

```
    void push(void(*call_function)){
        Node* newnode = new Node;
        newnode->next = Top;
        Top = newnode;
        Top->fn = call_function;
    }

    void* pop(){
        if(Top == nullptr){
            return nullptr;
        }
        void* ret = Top -> fn;
        Node* temp = Top;
        Top = Top->next;
        delete temp;

        return ret; 
    }
```

Example of intended use. Essentially when we call a function, at the end I add a function to the stack that will undo what we did. So when we pop the stack it undos the most recent.

```
   // Appends s to the end of the list; if necessary, the capacity of the
    // underlying array is doubled.
    //
    // undoable
    //
    void insert_back(const string &s)
    {
        insert_before(size(), s);
***        push((void*)remove_at(size()-1));
***
    }

    //
    // Inserts s at the front of the list; if necessary, the capacity of the
    // underlying array is doubled.
    //
    // undoable
    //
    void insert_front(const string &s)
    {
        insert_before(0, s);
***        push((void*)remove_at(0));
***
    }
```

I tried experimenting with casting to help with the pointers.
I tried a completly different implementation.
I tried going with out pointers

Comment: The expression `remove_at(0)` is *calling* the function `remove_at` with the argument `0`. You use its result to pass as argument to `push`. Also, you can't use `void*` pointers for pointers to functions. In your case use [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) to store callable objects, and use [lambdas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) instead.

Comment: More generally, whenever you feel the need to use either `void*` or a C-style cast when programming C++, you should take that as a sign that you're probably are doing something wrong.

Comment: Unless you're required to write your own stack, consider using `std::stack`. If you're required to write your own stack strongly consider making it a self-managing class rather than a bag of free functions that you have to manage manually.

Comment: This looks more like C than C++ to me.

Comment: Consider storing `std::function`s rather than function pointers.

Comment: [Using actual C++, not C++ that looks like C](https://godbolt.org/z/4PKxaGMWr).

Comment: Combine [std::stack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack), [std::function<void()>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [lambda expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) to get something like this `std::stack<std::function<void()> stack; std::string world{"world"}; stack.push([world]{ std::cout << "hello " << world; });`. That way you can use building blocks the standard library already made for you. (which can safe you a lot of debugging)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Amen

Answer (score 0):

`std::stack<std::function<void()>>`.

Just use that type (or `std::deque<std::function<void()>>`, or `std::vector<…>`.

It has push/pop/top/front/back and the like operations, and their use is well documented.

Using a std function means you could store a raw function pointer, or a lambda with extra state, as needed.